# How to create a chart in stack driver which will show the counts of API label from logs

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am very new to stack driver and trying to implement some charts which i have implemented in splunk for a different product.

We have the api name in the logs under textPaylod field and i want to extract the api name from the field and create a chart based on the counts of API names.

ex below is the sample log.

```
  type:  "k8s_container"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 textPayload:  "19-04-29T04:30:51.058+0000 INFO PostFilter: POST response to http://<endpoint>/abc/def/users/getNames
"  
 timestamp:  "2019-04-29T04:30:51.059143860Z"  
}
```

```
  type:  "k8s_container"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 textPayload:  "19-04-29T04:30:51.058+0000 INFO PostFilter: POST response to http://<endpoint>/abc/def/users/getPhoneNumbers
"  
 timestamp:  "2019-04-29T04:30:51.059143860Z"  
}
```

I've create a custom metric and extracted the text after "/abc/def" into API_NAME label expecting to use it as group function in the metric.

[Crating Custom Metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaYWQ.png)

When i tried to explore the metric and see the counts in a stacked bar i am not able to find the counts by apiname

[Metric Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1voa.png)

Answer (score 0):

When asking for help debugging a specific issue you've encountered following existing instructions, you may get a better response by emailing google-stackdriver-discussion@googlegroups.com .

As outlined in [Logs-based Metric Labels](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/labels), you should specify the appropriate capture group to extract the value of the label.

You can then see the time series for the logs-based metric you've created (see https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/troubleshooting for how to query the raw data). It's likely that your regular expression is not matching exactly what you think it's matching, and you are always getting an empty value for the `API_Name` label. One suspect is the escaped `\?` in your pattern — according to the [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), `?` should not be escaped.